# Constraint failed during the OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, constraintexception

I'm quite new with Ruby on Rails, so please bear with me.

I want to user to be able to sign in through Facebook. I've followed the railscast [#265 Devise and OmniAuth (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised). In the railscast the user is asked for a emailadres before he logs into Facebook. I want to user to be able to sign in through Facebook without the need of a emailadres beforehand.

What I use: The Devise and Omniauth-facebook gems

My expectation: The user clicks on the link, logs in through Facebook, Facebook returns email, name, uid, my app save that to the database and the user is created.

What I get: The error message `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook`

```
SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "name", "provider", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This is my user.rb model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  # Nodig als :validatable uit is
  #validates_presence_of   :email, :if => :email_required?
  #validates_uniqueness_of :email, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
  #validates_format_of     :email, :with  => Devise.email_regexp, :allow_blank => true, :if => :email_changed?
  #
  #validates_presence_of     :password, :if => :password_required?
  #validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :password_required?
  #validates_length_of       :password, :within => Devise.password_length, :allow_blank => true


  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.email
      user.name = auth.info.name
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def email_required?
    provider == :facebook
  end

  def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end

  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    if encrypted_password.blank?
      update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

This is my migration to add OmniAuth to the users (users already has email)

```
class AddOmniauthToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :provider, :string
    add_column :users, :uid, :string
    add_column :users, :name, :string
  end
end
```

And this is my OmniAuth Callback controller:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
      user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
      if user.persisted?
        flash.notice = "Loged in!"
        sign_in_and_redirect user
      else
        session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
    alias_method :facebook, :all  
end
```

Thanks in advance

Edit: Stack trace:

```
app/models/user.rb:23:in `from_omniauth'
app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:3:in `all'
```

Edit: Server log
The weird thing is. When I print `auth` I can see the name, email, provider and uid in the server log. However then this appears:

```
INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "name", "provider", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 26 Feb 2013 17:20:23 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["email", nil], ["encrypted_password", ""], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["name", nil], ["provider", "facebook"], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["uid", "XXXXX"], ["updated_at", Tue, 26 Feb 2013 17:20:23 UTC +00:00]]
SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "name", "provider", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The name, email is for instance `nil` but the provider and the uid (now XXXXX) is filled in. I added name and email myself in the user model. Maybe here is a problem? Might this help?

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace of the error? To me it seems that the database does not allow a field to be empty (don't know which one) and yet you provide it with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I put `p auth.info.email` (for a numerous of things you need to add the `.info`), the server logs shows the emailadress.

I thing it has to do with the fact that I changed my User model:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

The error is gone now. I added `user.save!` I changed to `auth.info.email` and I replaced `first_or_create` to `first_or_initialize.tap`

So when I look in the console (`User.all`), the email, name, uid and provider is in the database.

Apparently everything works out now. Tanks Harm for your help!

p.s: The server log still gives the questions marks, but does save the data in the records.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you either try to create a User without all it's required field OR you are trying to create a User which already exists (I suspect there is a uniqueness contraint on email).

To eliminate the later; remove all users from the users table.

To test the former; try creating a user with `User.create(some_params)` with the same params as you are giving to the `from_omniauth` method. To figure these out use something like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) or simply do:

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    p auth # Add this line and watch the logs.
    ....
end
```

What also might help is to look at your `db/schema.rb` (or `db/structure.sql` after running `rake db:structure:dump`) and see if there are any NOT NULL or UNIQUE constrains.

Comment: I removed all the users from the database (rake db:drop ect.). When I tried to add an user with Pry, it couldn't mass-assign name. I added the :uid and :name in my user model. Now I can add the name or the uid to a user in Pry. However I still get the same error in the browser (I've restarted the server)

Comment: Have your tried creating a user with the params which `from_omniauth` receives?

Comment: To be totally honest I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well, like I said in my answer. Go to line 23 in your User model, directly after the method definition add `p auth`. This will pretty print the variable `auth` to your log. Look for it in the console where you have run `rails s`. To make it stand out, add another line reading: `p "X"*100`. Then look for a long line of X's.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. I was missing `:provider` as well. Now I can create a user, in my console with all the params from `from_omniauth` (provider, uid, email and name).

Comment: I added the server log as well

Comment: The missing email etc seem to be problematic. So in the server logs you see the `auth` object?

Comment: I think there is something fundamentally wrong with your code, it's kinda hard to debug from here. Generally it seems that what you are trying to save a User with empty fields.

Also try putting `p auth.email` (or one of the others) in the block. See if that is sane.